# Powershell - How to find a pattern in a file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have in a file the output of a Visual Studio project build. I want to read that file, find the pattern and remove everthing in the file except that pattern itself.

The pattern to find looks like `23 failed`

The text file looks like that :

```
Microsoft Visual Studio  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.  
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug ------  
1>   Creating library S:\Test\Test.lib and object S:\Test\Test.exp  
1>Test.vcxproj -> S:\Test\Debug\Test.dll  
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 23 failed, 12 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work out:

```
$var = (Get-Content "$Path") -replace 's/.*(\d)+ failed.*'
```

Comment: /\s(\d. failed)/g
[more info](https://regex101.com/r/rQXifg/1) I think your query is preserving the entire line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a replace you can use name group to extract what you want :

```
Get-Content $Path | % { if ($_ -match '(?<FailCount>\d+ failed)') { $Matches["FailCount"] } }
```